# How to deform an ellipsis inside its englobing rectangle

Tags: modeling

[image: The orange mesh is the ellipsis. Black mesh is what I want to obtain.]

In the image above, I created the orange mesh (2D) by scaling a circle in an axis. So I got an ellipsis.

I created the black one point by point by moving each point of a circle with the mouse. The black curve is not an ellipsis, this is what I want.

How can I obtain the same result by applying a transformation which will move all points from the ellipsis between surrounded points, but surrounded points should not move and moved points should stay inside the rectangle defined by surrounded points.

In other words, I'd like to control the shape linking two perpendicular lines.

Comment: Curves are not an option I assume?

Comment: If I can use a curve for just this part of the object that's an option.

Comment: You can convert the curve to a mesh too

Comment: Thanxs for your comment. I cut my mesh, created a bezier curve, merged the curve and my mesh.

Comment: If that worked for you, go ahead and add an answer so others can follow your steps if they come across the same issue